# failed to build scs when installing cvxpy

Tags: pip, cvxpy, scs

trying to install cvxpy

```
pip3 install cvxpy
```

I get the following error message:

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scs
Failed to build scs
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scs, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

anyone has any light on the situation?

```
pip3 install cvxpy
```